# Disable phone calls while in certain apps

Tags: calls

I have lots of games on my phones, and they tend to have to restart when an incoming call comes in, even while hitting the Ignore button. Is there a way, on a rooted stock Android phone to set certain apps to *block* incoming calls, so the foreground app does not get interrupted? I am aware of Airplane mode, but that would require me to wait for it to activate, then turn my WiFi/Mobile Data back on, then go into the game, then remember to turn it back off.

Optionally, if I could set one or two phone numbers that *could* interrupt (i.e. Work or the spouse), that would be awesome too. My goal is that my phone knows not to disturb me if I'm in the middle of a game, without hitting 3 or 4 buttons before launching into the game, and remembering to disable something after leaving the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest build of Cyanogen Mod based off of Android 5 Lollipop, incoming notifications will not end the games. A drop down bubble that is easily dismissed is all that appears.

Answer (score 0):

Nope I dont thing there is an app to do that. The game developer has to build a game such away that when game starts airplane mode has to start or even a setting for to change airplane mode on/off. As far as I know apps cannot block incoming calls.

Workaound is you can try [Callcontrol](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flexaspect.android.everycallcontrol) and schedule the time to block calls